# ajuda para estruturar um if com resultados de uma lista

Tags: java

eu tenho 11 checkbox’s cada um tem um id igual ao id do banco de dados e o usuario pode selecionar mais de um checkbox
como estou usando java fx e scenebuilder inicalizei no meu controller

```
private CheckBox[] checkBoxes;

public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    initTable();
    tb.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
            selecionada = (Requisicao) newValue;
        }
    });

  checkBoxes = new CheckBox[] {
  checkMonitor,
  checkTeclado,
  checkMouse,
  checkVGA,
  checkPlacaMae,
  checkHD,
  checkFonte,
  checkRam,
  checkCabos,
  checkGravador,
  checkBateria
    };  

}
```

aqui eu pego os id’s dos checkbox selecionados e guardo em uma lista e passo como parametro para meu DAO

```
public void xd(){
    List<Integer> pecasList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkBoxes[i].isSelected()) {
            pecasList.add(i+1);
        }
    }
    Alerts alerts = new Alerts();
    PecasDAO pecas = new PecasDAO();
    pecas.pegarPecasById(pecasList);
    for (Pecas checarQtd : pecas.pegarPecasById(pecasList)){
        if(checarQtd.getQtd_Pecas()>0){
            alerts.alertReqCadastrado();
        }else{
            alerts.alertSenhaDif();
        }
    }

}
```

o meu DAO

```
public List<Pecas> pegarPecasById(List<Integer> ids) {
    List<Pecas> pecaslist = new ArrayList<>();
if (ids.isEmpty()) {
    return new ArrayList<>(0);
} else {
    String sql = ids.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(",", "SELECT * FROM pecas WHERE id_pecas IN (", ")"));

    try {
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {       
            Pecas pecas = new Pecas();
            pecas.setIdpecas(rs.getInt("id_pecas"));
            pecas.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
            pecas.setQtd_Pecas(rs.getInt("qtdPecas"));
            pecaslist.add(pecas);
        }
        stmt.close();
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RequisicaoDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return null;
    }
    return pecaslist;
}   
}
```

no meu DAO eu faço uma consulta no banco de dados e pego os valores da tabela peças
que são:
id / nome_peça/ quantidade disponivel

e então eu percorro essa lista no meu controller:

```
pecas.pegarPecasById(pecasList);
for (Pecas checarQtd : pecas.pegarPecasById(pecasList)){
    if(checarQtd.getQtd_Pecas()>0){
        alerts.alertReqCadastrado();
    }else{
        alerts.alertSenhaDif();
    }
}
```

minha dificuldade está nessa parte
pois eu tenho todos os dados com essa lista: ex se o usuario selecionar 3 checkbox’s eu vou fazer essa consulta no banco de dados de acordo com o id e irei pegar a quantidade de peças disponível

e então eu queira fazer um if para fazer essa verificação, caso o usuario tenha marcado um checkbox e esse id não tenha uma quantidade de peças > 0 eu gerar um alert ( não temos estoque )
e caso tenha
eu enviar essa como parametro para um DAO para inserir em outra tabela
toda a minha dificuldade está em como estruturar esse if
do jeito que está caso eu selecione 5 check box’s e apenas um tiver quantidade maior do q > 0
irá aparecer 1 alert de sucesso, e 4 alert’s de falha.

tava pensando em criar 2 listas uma para adicionar os valores que não tem estoque maior do que 0 e outra para os que tem
e depois no if verificar se tem valores nessas listas no if, mas não sei se é possível.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, vc já parou para pensar, que se não tem o item em estoque, vc nem deveria mostrar essa opção para o cliente?
Ou, você deveria validar se tem estoque antes de adicionar na sua lista, funciona basicamente com um carrinho de qualquer E-Commerce.
Assim que vc consegue mostrar a mensagem para cada item, sem complicar muito seu código.

Comment: mt obrigado mano eu acabei me passando por essa opção eu tinha achado uma solução, mas vou fazer novamento.